# Sync data from core data

Tags: core-data

Hi  have used core data to save data  instead of NSUserdefaults 
How to sync data automatically  like we do using[[ Nsuserdefaults Standarddefults] synchronize] ;
How to do this using core data

Comment: If you have already used Core Data to save data, what are you looking for besides the `save` method?

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab your managedObjectContext wherever it is: NSManagedObjectContext
2. Create a fetch request with the entity name of the managed object you want to fetch: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity Name")
3. Then execute a fetch request on your managedObjectContext

   ```
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
   var people: [Person]
   do {
     people = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
   } catch let error as NSError {
     print("error occured while fetching: \(error)")
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh OK thanks I got it  and I saved it and do we need to sync automatically from database  like we do in Nsuserdefaults

Comment: calling save on the context automatically saves the changes to the persistence store, so you do not have to synchronize like you do with NSUserdefaults.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest

Comment: am getting that error i have tried solving similar to that in stackoveflow but didnt worked for me